# Getting {status:"empty"} when visiting a freshly deployed website

Tags: html, browser, windows-server-2012

I have just deployed a simple website consisting of HTML, CSS and some lightweight jquery and when I visit the page, all I can see is:

```
{status:"empty"}
```

That happens only on some browsers, like Chrome and IE 9,8 etc.

Any idea what am I missing?

I am hosting it on Windows Server 2012, IIS.

Comment: You probably have a misconfigured server.  You should note in your question if you're using Apache, nginx, heroku, etc.

Comment: I am using windows IIS, thank you I will update my question.